# Why are these tuple values seemingly losing their precision

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following:

```
import pandas as pd
def TupFirst(x):
    return x[0]
def TupSecond(x):
    return x[1]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'colX': [(51.2990505474, 0.802680507953),(51.7491674401, -4.96357522689)]})
df['colY'] = df['colX'].apply(TupFirst)
df['colZ'] = df['colX'].apply(TupSecond)
df
```

Which returns the following dataframe:

```
    colX                                colY        colZ
0   (51.2990505474, 0.802680507953)     51.299051   0.802681
1   (51.7491674401, -4.96357522689)     51.749167   -4.963575
```

Why are the values in colY and colZ being rounded?

Comment: You can see it is stored full precision if you do `df.colY[0]` for instance. The rounding is just due to output settings, which you can change by [changing the options](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html).

Comment: `pd.set_option('precision',10)` should add more digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the result of a display configuration in pandas. The full precision is still there. Check it with:

`print(df.loc[1, 'colz'])`